# What does "blue's my colour" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Monica: How are you?
>
> Fake Monica: I'm not too bad. Fortunately, **blue's my colour**. How-how
>   did you know I was here?
>
> Monica: Because... I'm Monica Geller. It was my credit card you were
>   using.

It is from the sitcom *Friends* season 1 episode 21.

To me, "blue's my colour" barely makes any sense in this context.

Comment: Fake Monica is in prison. All inmates have to wear the same blue uniform... not really that funny a pun.

Comment: It means that the colour blue is one of the colours she believes complements her natural colouring. Since this would be extremely unlikely, she means it in a sarcastic sense with shades of making a virtue out of a necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*X is my color* means that the speaker looks or feels attractive wearing the color X. Since blue is the color of the prison uniforms, she's pointing out the silver lining of having been arrested for identity theft.

Comment: And I'll bet her face was red. :)